# Error Reading Pandas HDFStore (with PyTables)

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables, hdf

I have a pandas HDFStore object (pandas uses PyTables to implement HDF5 if that is relevant) with a `mydata` DataFrame (`store["mydata"] = mydata`) and have some code that regularly appends data to the `mydata` DataFrame. When I try to access that HDFStore, I get this error.

```
//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/group.py:1213: UserWarning: problems loading leaf ``/mydata/table``::

  HDF5 error back trace

  File "H5Dio.c", line 173, in H5Dread
    can't read data
  File "H5Dio.c", line 551, in H5D__read
    can't read data
  File "H5Dchunk.c", line 1872, in H5D__chunk_read
    unable to read raw data chunk
  File "H5Dchunk.c", line 2902, in H5D__chunk_lock
    data pipeline read failed
  File "H5Z.c", line 1375, in H5Z_pipeline
    filter returned failure during read
  File "H5Zdeflate.c", line 125, in H5Z_filter_deflate
    inflate() failed

End of HDF5 error back trace

Problems reading the array data.

The leaf will become an ``UnImplemented`` node.
  % (self._g_join(childname), exc))
```

This is what the store looks like when I print it.

```
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: ../path/to/panda/store.h5
/mydata               [invalid_HDFStore node: 'UnImplemented' object has no attribute 'description']
```

Im not sure why this is happening.

To work with the data, I copied and pasted the `.h5` file from another location (without calling `.close()` if that matters). Could this be the source of the error or is it because I'm appending the data with `format=table`?

Comment: you file is broken. you *have* to always call ``.close()``. HDF5 does some cleanup when this happens.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: In my case, @Jeff suggestion helped. I closed open hdf5 file, and then opened again.